# Apache setting confusion

Tags: apache-2.2

What is the difference between document root and directory?

Besides, say there are 2 files at

C:\A\test.txt
C:\B\test.txt

and the setting is like this

document root = "C:\A";
directory = "C:\B";

which file will this URL reference to ht tp://localhost/test.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocumentRoot and Directory are used differently from one another.

From [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot):

```
DocumentRoot
```

The directory that forms the main document tree visible from the web. This directive sets the directory from which httpd will serve files. Unless matched by a directive like Alias, the server appends the path from the requested URL to the document root to make the path to the document. The DocumentRoot should be specified without a trailing slash.

From [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory):

Enclose a group of directives that apply only to the named file-system directory, sub-directories, and their contents.

```
<Directory> and </Directory>
```

Are used to enclose a group of directives that will apply only to the named directory, sub-directories of that directory, and the files within the respective directories. Any directive that is allowed in a directory context may be used. Directory-path is either the full path to a directory, or a wild-card string using Unix shell-style matching. In a wild-card string, ? matches any single character, and * matches any sequences of characters. You may also use [] character ranges. None of the wildcards match a `/' character, so  will not match /home/user/public_html, but  will match. Be careful with the directory-path arguments: They have to literally match the filesystem path which Apache uses to access the files. Directives applied to a particular  will not apply to files accessed from that same directory via a different path, such as via different symbolic links.

**Examples of each type can be found on the Apache2 documentation links above.**